# How to inject NLog using Autofac

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm writing a WinForm App using Autofac and NLog. And so I created an interface:
namespace BookShopApp.Logging

```
{
    public interface ILoggerService<T> where T : class
    {
        void Info(string message);
        void Warn(string message);
        void Error(string message);
        void Trace(string message);
    }
}
```

Then implement it

```
    public class LoggerService<T> : ILoggerService<T> where T : class
    {
        public Logger _logger { get; set; }

        public LoggerService(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(T).FullName);
        }

        public void Error(string message)
        {
            _logger.Error(message);
        }

        public void Info(string message)
        {
            _logger.Info(message);
        }

        public void Trace(string message)
        {
            _logger.Trace(message);
        }

        public void Warn(string message)
        {
            _logger.Warn(message);
        }
    }
```

After this I Registered this in module

```
    internal class ServiceModule:Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<GetBookService>().As<IGetBookService>();
            builder.RegisterType<AddPublisherService>().As<IAddPublisherService>();
            builder.RegisterType<AddAuthorService>().As<IAddAuthorService>();
            builder.RegisterType<AddBookService>().As<IAddBookService>();
            builder.RegisterType<GetPublisherService>().As<IGetPublishersService>();
            builder.RegisterType<GetAuthorsService>().As<IGetAuthorsService>();
            builder.RegisterType<SaleBookService>().As<ISaleBookService>();
            builder.RegisterType<ChangePriceService>().As<IChangePriceService>();
            builder.RegisterType<GetPublisherByNameService>().As<IGetPublisherByNameService>();
            builder.RegisterType<CreateCartService>().As<ICreateCartService>();
            builder.RegisterType<GetLastCartDetails>().As<IGetLastCartDetails>();
            builder.RegisterType<RemoveUnsoldCartsService>().As<IRemoveUnsoldCartsService>();
            builder.RegisterType<CreateBookListToChangeService>().As<ICreateBookListToChangeService>();
            builder.RegisterType<GetBooksToChangeService>().As<IGetBooksToChangeService>();
            builder.RegisterType<RemoveUnchangedBooksService>().As<IRemoveUnchangedBooksService>();
            builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(LoggerService<>)).As(typeof(ILoggerService<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>();
            builder.RegisterType<DataContext>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<PurchaseBooksReport>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<BooksOfAuthorReport>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<AddPublisherForm>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<AddAuthorForm>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<AddBookForm>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<ChangePriceForm>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<CreateSaleForm>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<BookShopForm>();
            builder.RegisterType<ReportsForm>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Program).Assembly)
                .AssignableTo<DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm>()
                .AsSelf();
        }
```

```
       static void Main()
        {
            // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
            // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterModule<ServiceModule>();

            using var container=builder.Build();
            var form=container.Resolve<BookShopForm>();
            Application.Run(form);
        }
```

And running the app I got the Exception
"No accessible constructors were found for the type 'NLog.Logger'."
I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. This is because Logger don't have public ctors. So then how to inject it?

Comment: Try making this [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You have a LOT of code in here that has nothing to do with the issue. Include the whole exception, not just the message. [Read the troubleshooting docs](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting/index.html), they may help you understand the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe register Microsoft Extensions Logging `LoggerFactory` + `ILogger` in AutoFac:

```cs
    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<LoggerFactory>()
                    .As<ILoggerFactory>()
                    .SingleInstance();
    containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>))
                    .As(typeof(ILogger<>))
                    .SingleInstance();
```

And then register NLog as logging-provider using [NLog.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging):

```
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
    var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();
```

Then you can acquire a typed `ILogger<T>`:

```
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<ServiceModule>>().LogDebug("Logging initialized!");
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/issues/225

Answer (score 0):

My current implementation

```
 using NLog;

namespace Core.Aspects.Log
{
    public class Logger : ILog
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger =  LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public void Error(string message)
        {
            _logger.Error(message);
        }

        public void Fatal(string message)
        {
            _logger.Fatal(message);
        }

        public void Info(string message)
        {
            _logger.Info(message);  
        }

        public void Warn(string message)
        {
            _logger.Warn(message);
        }
    }
}

 services.AddSingleton<ILog, Logger>();


public interface ILog
    {
        void Info(string message);
        void Error(string message);
        void Fatal(string message);
        void Warn(string message);
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work